# Can I delete first character when use execcommand function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, execcommand

Can I delete first character using `execCommand` function in JavaScript?

So, I need to that:

```
"My string..."
document.execCommand('...');
"y string..."
```

I have code that;

```js
$('#myDiv').keydown(function(e) {
    var sel = document.getSelection(),
        nd = sel.anchorNode,
        text = nd.textContent.slice(0, sel.focusOffset),
        col = text.split("\n").pop();
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 13:
            if (e.shiftKey) {
                // ....
            }
            break;
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: execcommand: `This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What command are you passing as argument to `document.execCommand()`? Are you trying to cut/copy some text from element? If you just want to remove first charecter from a string use [String.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Comment: but ... here are the [list of commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Commands) - does any fulfil your requirements

Comment: I working on a contenteditable div. When press TAB + SHIFT keys, it should delete first character of cursor located line. Or, Can I do that with String.substring()?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the first character of a string, you can use [`substring(1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) function:

```js
let str = "My string...";
let res = str.substring(1);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: But I must do it on contenteditable div and current line?

Comment: Could you elaborate

Comment: Now, I have a contenteditable div. I need to, when press TAB + SHIFT keys, it must delete first character on current line (cursor located line).

Comment: could you edit your question with the code you are attempting to change.

Comment: still not clear what string are you trying to delete first character from.

Comment: Think that,
You writing codes. And you opened a code block with "{" symbol. At after this line, you added more 1 tab space and typed something after that. In some cases, it may be easier to press the TAB and SHIFT keys and delete the first tab space in the row. Did you got it?

Comment: Which variable / div in your code above is being modified here?

Comment: My problem is that, I could not modify the current line.

Comment: I guess nobody helps me :(

Comment: It is actually not clear what the problem is - sorry.